# groupIdx parameter of spark regexp_extract function

Tags: sql, regex, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I don't understand how last parameter **groupIdx** works in below function, I can't find any details in documentation. I am using this function with groupIdx = 0, when I changed this value to > 0, I've received an error `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 1`. Can someone explain how it works and when groupIdx > 0 could be applied?

```
regexp_extract(e: Column, exp: String, groupIdx: Int): Column
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument extracts the part of a match that was captured with the specified [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

See the [docs](https://people.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-nightly/spark-master-docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#regexp_extract):

> `regexp_extract(str, regexp[, idx]) - Extracts a group that matches regexp.`
>   **Examples:**
>   `> SELECT regexp_extract('100-200', '(\d+)-(\d+)', 1);`
>   `100`

The `100` substring is captured with the first `(\d+)` in the regex pattern, and the `1` argument makes the function return just this part of the whole match (which is `100-200`).